# Grid Layout Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, grid-layout

I have created a java program that shows a grid of buttons and labels and i want to know how to pit a constraint on the labels and buttons so they dont re-size when window is dragged out.. can anyone help please?

this is my gridlayout class

```
package JFrameTester;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class layout extends JFrame {

    JButton button1,button2,button3;
    JLabel label1,Label2,Label3;

    public layout (){

    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    button1 =  new JButton ("button1");

    add(button1);

    label1 =  new JLabel ("label1");
    add(label1);

    button2 =  new JButton ("button1");
    add(button2);

    Label2 =  new JLabel ("Label2");
    add(Label2);

    button3 =  new JButton ("button1");
    add(button3);

    Label3 =  new JLabel ("Label3");
    add(Label3);

        }


}
```

and this is my main class

```
public class JFrameTester {


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


    layout Lay = new layout();
     Lay.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     Lay.setVisible(true);


    // JFrame frame = new JFrame("BUY COMPUTER");

    Lay.setSize(800, 600);
        //frame.pack();
   //  frame.setVisible(true);
     Lay.addWindowListener(new MyWindowListener());
 }
}
```

Comment: You have given your class name 'layout' which is wrong. Because according to Java naming conventions class name should always begin with a Capital Letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the labels and buttons inside a `JPanel`, and then add that `JPanel` to your `GridLayout`. `GridLayout` automatically resizes components to fit the size of the cell they are placed in and when a `JFrame` is resized it will adjust the components size as needed. If you place them in `JPanel`s only the `JPanel` in that cell will be resized, not the components.

**EDIT**

In addition to that it's Java practice to name all classes with an uppercase letter, your `layout` should be `Layout`. However, the name `Layout` does not accurately convey the purpose of class `Layout` as your class is not *a* layout, it's a `JFrame`. Perhaps `LayoutFrame` would be a better class name.

And (this is default Java practice) variables should be camelcase, beginning with a lowercase letter and subsequent words having a capital letter e.g. `thisIsAVariable`. Alternatively you could use underscores which is not normal Java practice, `this_is_a_varaible`. Given that in Java classes generally start with a capital letter and variables start with a lowercase letter the statement `layout Lay = new layout();` looks very strange and a bit confusing at first glance.